# How do you say "can't choose" in a good way?

Tags: grammar

I need to provide a quote for a large project with price breakups, but I don't want the client to choose only a few things from it, either they go ahead with the project or don't.

I can't find a suitable work for it.  "Mutually exclusive" maybe, not sure.

Comment: Is _all-or-nothing_ too negative for your tastes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could say:

> We're not selling anything ***à la carte***; you have to buy the ***whole package***.

The word *package* is often used to express exactly what you're inquiring about. From NOAD:

> **package** (*n.*) (also ***package deal***) a set of proposals or terms offered or agreed to as a whole

Although *à la carte* originally referred to a way of ordering food, the expression has been extended to other areas of business as well. For example, a 2013 article on education is headlined: *'A La Carte' Purchasing Tactics Signal Districts’ Unique Needs*; it says:

> Many are pursuing an à la carte approach to procurement — still relying on traditional 
> providers for large, multigrade programs, but also forging partnerships with smaller
>  companies to supply innovative products and platforms.

Answer (score 0):

What about "offering as a single package (only)"?

Comment: I'd like this suggestion better if it used the more common idiom: _it's a **package deal**._

Comment: 'Individual components not available separately.'